# Unexpected token } at html tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

While using php, and doing several things I append this code to a HTML tag:

```
$tmp = $result[$i]['name'];
echo '<p><a href="#" onClick="setFood("'.$temp.'")"><b>'.$tmp.'</b></a></p>';
```

here is the setFood function

```
function setFood(food){
localStorage.clear();
localStorage.setItem('currentFood', food);
window.location.replace("food_specification.html");
}
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

and it redirects me to this:

```
(function(event){setFood(
})
```

Marking the error at the second line. and somethings it redirects to the `html` tag.
Also if I remove the href and the function that I want to use it works:

```
echo '<p><a href="food_specification.html"><b>'.$tmp.'</b></a></p>';
```

Any idea what the problem can be? All the js are being implemented correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output will be `onClick="setFood("temp")"`,try below:

`echo '<p><a href="#" onClick="setFood(\''.$temp.'\')"><b>'.$tmp.'</b></a></p>';`

Comment: It really did the trick... si it's a mess with the quotes as KaNa said in the other comment...
I can't accept two answers so I'm going with the first one(1 min difference lol)
Thanks, I've been breaking my head with this.

Answer (score 0):

All \' instead of ". The html isn't well formed because the double quotes mismatch.